# Querying DataSet with LIKE and OR using LINQ with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have a `DataSet` where there is a column called `PName`, `PCode` and `PDesc`. Is there anyway that i could set my datasource based on a query something like

```
gridview.DataSource = Get me everything where PName LIKE 'somevalue' 
                      OR PCode LIKE 'somevalue' 
                      OR PDesc LIKE 'somevalue'
```

I have tried to find about using LINQ but i do not see any with OR's , is this possible?. I would appreciate any pointers / help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this out:

```
gridview.DataSource = from d in DataSetVar.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  where d.Field<string>("PName").IndexOf("stringToFind1") >= 0 ||
                  d.Field<string>("PCode ").IndexOf("stringToFind2") >= 0 ||
                  d.Field<string>("PDesc").IndexOf("stringToFind3") >= 0
                  select d;
```

Also, AsEnumerable is part of the System.Data.DataSetExtensions library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logical OR operator (`||`) from within a Where clause.  There's not a LIKE function but you can accomplish something similar using the `string` functions `BeginsWith`, `EndsWith`, or `Contains` (depending on how you're using LIKE):

```
where ("somevalue".Contains(PName) || 
       "somevalue".Contains(PCode) ||  
       "somevalue".Contains(PDesc) )
```

Comment: PName , PCode and PDesc are the columns, and somevalue is the value.. so I would pass the name of the column in the contains?